# WebDriver closed or session timeout or NoSuchWindowException when authentication window appears(only on IE)

Tags: c#, json, session, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We are working selenium WebDriver with c# bindings, and building page factory model as per our requirement.

We are facing issue: Selenium WebDriver session timeout or driver closed

Let me explain in two ways where this issue persisting:

1. If I open non securable URL1 (where we don't require to pass user authentication details to access the page) and then if you navigate with another URL2 (here we need to pass user credentials to access this page) on the same browser, then we are seeing WebDriver session time out or no such window exception or driver closed.
2. If we open non-securable URL2 site (where we need to pass users credentials) and then we can continue with the same session for other pages by passing different URLs and no issues in this case.

From the above cases, what we observed, if 1st I open securable site URL then I can continue with my work without any issues.
But if 1st I open non-securable and then securable, in this case Selenium WebDriver throwing an error NoSuchwindowException. It is because of the authentication window was in-front of the page (might be).

can any one add solution to overcome from this issue?

note: Which is happening on on IE but on other chrome and FF working fine.
but we have to test our application on IE.